# What security issues can I possibly run into by having 3rd party RSS feeds on a secure page

Tags: security, iframe, rss

I have a page over https. This has an iframe on it, and the domain of the iframe is the same as top.

This iframe uses google feed reader ([gfdynamicfeedcontrol](http://code.google.com/p/google-ajax-examples/source/browse/trunk/translationgame/gfdynamicfeedcontrol.js?r=76)) to read rss feeds from 3rd party sites.

What security issues can I run into with this setup, and is there a better way to do this?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As long as it's static content such as just images or a calculation script it's probably fine.  The problem is that someone may load content which really should have been secured via SSL.  This means that the browser freaks out when it notices pages which have both secure and unsecure content on them and will warn users.  This can scare users away from your site potentially.

You're going to have browser warnings everywhere if you go with this setup.

Comment: Well, since both the top and iframe are on the same domain, both are being served from https. Just that the content of the iframe that is being parsed by google's feed reader is coming from an rss feed from another site. Browser doesn't complain generally. It would have if my iframe src wasn't https or different domain.

Comment: Even the gfdynamicfeedcontrol is coming off the same domain over https. Only external part of the whole scenerio is this snippet of code that is needed for the feed reader -

function load() {
    var feed = "http link to rss feed of some outside website";
    new GFdynamicFeedControl(feed, "somename", options);
}

Comment: Then the only possible security issue you have is if someone grabs that little snipit in transit (man in the middle attack) and decides to substitute it for something of their choosing such as some javascript which records each key press using a global event hook and sends it back to them.